# node keystone Cannot find module './browserify'

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

Everything was working until I did a `npm install` on my project folder.

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.5, node.js v8.2.1, npm v5.3.0

What I have tried:

- uninstalling node/npm and reinstalling
- npm install -g browserify
- npm insatll browserify on my project folder
- reinstall KeystoneJS generator

my package.json

```
   {
  "name": "site-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "keystone": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "consolidate": "0.14.5",
    "nunjucks": "3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "4.5.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "0.11.0",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "async": "2.1.4",
    "express-sslify": "1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "3.15.0",
    "eslint-config-keystone": "3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "node keystone.js"
  }
}
```

Here is the output in terminal

```
node keystone
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './browserify'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Forge_Fitness_Site/models/node_modules/sha.js/bin.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /Users/Tyler/Desktop/Forge_Fitness_Site/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/importer.js:42:23
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at importer (/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Forge_Fitness_Site/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/importer.js:32:26)
    at /Users/Tyler/Desktop/Forge_Fitness_Site/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/importer.js:36:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at importer (/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Forge_Fitness_Site/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/importer.js:32:26)
    at /Users/Tyler/Desktop/Forge_Fitness_Site/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/importer.js:36:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at importer (/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Forge_Fitness_Site/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/importer.js:32:26)
    at Keystone.import (/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Forge_Fitness_Site/node_modules/keystone/index.js:176:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Forge_Fitness_Site/keystone.js:41:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Comment: I ran the `yo generator` and created a new test site. Upon completion, I was able to run `node keystone` successfully on the new site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed the issue, not exactly sure how it happened but somehow I ended up with two node_modules folders in my project directory. Deleting the second one fixed my issue.